# How to implement Audio calling on sockets in Android

Tags: android, audio, stream, voip, voice

I have searched and found a code of voice streaming or audio calling between two android phones on simple sockets. I have implemented this , but this code is not working. I am unable to hear any voice.

Receiver Code :

```
    private int sampleRate = 44100;
    private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;    
    private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       
    int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);


public void startReceiving() {

        Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(50005);
                    Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");


                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);



                    while(status == true) {
                        try {


                            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                            socket.receive(packet);
                            Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                            //reading content from packet
                            buffer=packet.getData();
                            Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                            //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                            speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);

                            Log.d("VR", String.valueOf(buffer));

                            speaker.play();

                        } catch(IOException e) {
                            Log.e("VR","IOException");
                        }
                    }


                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    Log.e("VR", "SocketException");
                }


            }

        });
        receiveThread.start();
    }
```

Sender Code:

```
public void startStreaming() {
        Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                    Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                    DatagramPacket packet;

                    final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.216");
                    Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");


                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize*10);
                    Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                    recorder.startRecording();


                    while(status == true) {


                        //reading data from MIC into buffer
                        minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                        //putting buffer in the packet
                        packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);

                        socket.send(packet);
                    }

                } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                    Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                } 
            }

        });
        streamThread.start();
     }
```

I debugged the code , and packets are successfully transmitting and `speaker.play()` is also called. But there is no `Voice`

I have implemented this code in a single application and activity. With two Buttons `Start Listening` and `Start Streaming`

Answer (score 2):

`getMinBufferSize()` may not be the same for `AudioRecord` and `AudioTrack` (learned that the hard way). Make sure you are using the larger of the two.

Comment: Is this the Solution?,don't understand what you really mean.

Comment: As you can see in his code, he is assuming that minBufSize from AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize() is the same value as AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(). This was a blocking point for me for some time because I made that assumption as well before. When debugging I found out that AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize() was returning twice the size of AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize() (or the other way around, I can't remember), so the recorder was not filling the AudioTrack with enough data to play a sound.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine for me... just want to ask that how to send packets on public `IP` like `119.43.214.5`. I have made two apps and they can send packets on `localhost` Client have got the `IP` Address of server app. Just the problem is that `IP` is a public `IP` and client is not sending data on that app.